# Saving Chemfig submolecules in a separate file, to be recovered into beamer

Tags: beamer, input, chemfig

Please consider the following code

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{1st frame}
\definesubmol{x}{-[:+30,.6]-[:-30,.6]}
\definesubmol{y}{-O-(=[2,.6]O)-!x!x!x!x!x!x!x!x}
\chemfig{[2,0.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{2nd frame}
\chemfig{[2,0.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is to build submolecules first and then assemble them in successive frames.
If I write the submolecules that I need within each frame, soon the whole code become complicate and cluttered.

The only solution I was able to find was to save the submolecules in an external .tex file, to be invoked each time from within frames when needed.

Something like the following

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer} 
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{1st frame}
    \input{submoleculesChemfig.tex}
    \chemfig{[2,0.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{2nd frame}
     \input{submoleculesChemfig.tex}    
     \chemfig{[2,0.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)-[,1.5]([0]!y)}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Is there a better solution, without using the external file ?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put the `\definesubmol` declarations in the preamble?

Comment: Do you know about beamer's `\only` `\pause` and `\onslide` commands?

Comment: Thanks cgnieder. I'm after building molecules and I forgot the basics !!

For Seamus; yes I know thos commands. It is exactly because I have to use them intensively, that I want my code a little bit cleaner and readable.

Comment: @Seamus. There are issues with using `\onslide` and `chemfig`. This may not be the issue here but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98349/uncover-chemfig-molecule-in-beamer .