# ChemFig, Beamer, and Uncover

Tags: beamer, chemfig, chemistry

I want to utilize `beamer`'s `\uncover` command within ChemFig's reaction scheme environment, i.e.:

```
\schemestart
    \chemname[-1ex]{\chemfig[][scale=1]{*5(-=(-=[:-60]O)-O-=)}}{Furfural}
    \uncover<2->{
        \arrow(furfural--mf){->[*{0}HDO][]}
        \chemname[-1ex]{\chemfig{*5(-=(-)-O-=)}}{2-Methylfuran}
    }
\schemestop
```

However, this results in numerous "undefined control sequence" errors.

Is there a way to use `beamer`'s `\uncover` command within ChemFig?

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stuff}

\schemestart
    \chemname[0ex]{\chemfig[][scale=1]{*5(-=(-=[:-60]O)-O-=)}}{Furfural}
    \uncover<2->{
        \arrow(furfural--mf){->[*{0}\textbf{HDO}][]}
        \chemname[0ex]{\chemfig{*5(-=(-)-O-=)}}{2-Methylfuran}
    }
\schemestop

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98360/36296

Comment: The `visibile on` trick works okay; however there are two issues that I cannot seem to work around:

1) When I apply it to a `\arrow`, and compile the PDF, all my molecules "dance", i.e., they spuriously move. Is there a solution around this?

2) I have some rather large molecules I want to apply this to. Is there a way to apply `visible on` to the whole molecule, as opposed a singular bond?

Comment: Can you update your MWE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a quick workaround: divide your molecules into individual `scheme`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stuff}

\schemestart
\chemname[0ex]{\chemfig[][scale=1]{*5(-=(-=[:-60]O)-O-=)}}{Furfural}
\schemestop
\uncover<2->{
\raisebox{1em}{
\schemestart
    \arrow(furfural--mf){->[*{0}\textbf{HDO}][]}
    \chemname[0ex]{\chemfig{*5(-=(-)-O-=)}}{2-Methylfuran}
\schemestop
}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And we have a winner!

This works like a charm --- did not think the nodes would carry over from scheme to scheme like that!

Comment: Answers one of my comments in the http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98360/36296 question, specifically for reaction schemes. Perfect!